# Getting a Error during PHP connection to mysql in webmatrix

Tags: php, mysql, webmatrix

I am getting a error when trying to connect to mysql database from a php file in webmatrix,The details are as below

This is the PHP File :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$database = "image" ;

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
echo "Connected successfully";
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the web.config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=image;Uid=root;Pwd=password" name="image" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />     
    </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

This is the error I am getting :

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
Most likely causes:
A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.

More Information:
This error occurs when a document is not specified in the URL, no default document is specified for the Web site or application, and directory listing is not enabled for the Web site or application. This setting may be disabled on purpose to secure the contents of the server.
```

Comment: $password = "password"; ??

Answer (score 0):

i got this resolved by changing the web.config file to add default document as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=image;Uid=root;Pwd=hrushikesh" name="image" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />     
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="sample.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```